# Fatal Error Globally with Slim PHP Requests

Tags: php, nginx, slim

I'm experiencing a problem with all the requests in my app. The below error is returned in about 20% of requests, no matter a specific request, it seems to be indiscriminate in frequency based on the request. This problem started appearing when I decided to run the app locally on my new computer, so I'm guessing it's an environment issue. Given the infrequency of it and my unfamiliarity with the Slim core I feel at a loss to address this issue.

I'm running PHP-FPM - running PHP 5.3.27 - on top of Nginx. I'm running Slim 2.4.0 Let me know if you need to know any php.ini values, the modules in the PHP install, or anything else relevant. Since it's an issue global to the app I'm not sure exactly what code to include. Thanks a lot for your help.

```
Notice: Undefined property: Slim\Slim::$container in Slim/Slim.php on line 234

Notice: Indirect modification of overloaded property Slim\Slim::$container has no effect in Slim/Slim.php on line 239

Notice: Undefined property: Slim\Slim::$container in Slim/Slim.php on line 234

Notice: Indirect modification of overloaded property Slim\Slim::$container has no effect in Slim/Slim.php on line 155

Notice: Undefined property: Slim\Slim::$container in Slim/Slim.php on line 234

Fatal error: Call to a member function singleton() on a non-object in Slim/Slim.php on line 158
```

Below is the top of my index.php (where all non-file requests get routed) showing the instantiation of the \Slim\Slim object. There's nothing but constant definitions in config.php and all the responses are defined in lines following these:

```
/**
* Define Constants
 */
require_once 'config.php';

/**
 * Require the Slim Framework
 *
 * If you are not using Composer, you need to require the
 * Slim Framework and register its PSR-0 autoloader.
 *
 * If you are using Composer, you can skip this step.
 */
require 'Slim/Slim.php';
\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();

/**
 * Instantiate a Slim application
 *
 * This example instantiates a Slim application using
 * its default settings. However, you will usually configure
 * your Slim application now by passing an associative array
 * of setting names and values into the application constructor.
 */
$app = new \Slim\Slim(array(
    'mode' => 'development',
    'debug' => false,
    'log.enabled' => false,
    'templates.path' => APPPATH . '/templates',
    'cookies.encrypt' => true,
    'cookies.lifetime' => '12 hour',
    'cookies.secret_key' => '$apr1$4s961sza$txDJLrSg2suGYqkWf24wL.'
));

$res = $app->response();
$res['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
```

Comment: What version of Slim?

Comment: Looking [here](https://github.com/codeguy/Slim/blob/2.3.0/Slim/Slim.php#L153) I can't see any way that `$container` could not be set. How are you instantiating the `\Slim\Slim` object? Also, I'd suggest upgrading to 2.4.0

Comment: **[Here's](http://pastebin.com/gvZua7Mg)** the top of my index.php, in config.php is just a definition of a number of constants. All of my responses are broken out into their own required files below these lines.

Comment: Please update your question instead of linking to a pastebin. Also, `global $app`, ew :(

Comment: Updated. The global scope was a hack for a middleware issue, I've actually since fixed it the right way, but forgot to remove that. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Updated to Slim 2.4.0, and I'm still seeing the same problem. I've updated my question to update the line numbers in the error.